# Is this map $F:V^*\times V\to \mathbb R$ a basis-free definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $2$.

Let $\{w_1,w_2\}$ be a basis of $V$ and $\{\beta_1,\beta_2\}\subset  V^*$ its dual basis.

Let $T:V^*\times V^*\times V\times V \to \mathbb R$ be a multiliear map.

Let $F:V^*\times V\to \mathbb R$ be the multiliear map defined by

$$F(u,v)=\sum_{k=1}^2T(\beta_k,u,w_k,v).$$

**Question:** Is the definition of $F$ indepentend of the fixed basis $\{w_1,w_2\}$ of $V$? In other words, does any basis give the same $F$?

If so, is it trivial? This is a remark in some notes but I couldn't prove it by myself. I would appreciate an explanation of the proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is. You just have to check that the value agree for all basis. That is if the basis transform as
$$
w_k = \sum_{\alpha = 1}^{2} A_{\alpha k} w'_{\alpha}
$$
and by condition $\beta_k(w_l) = \delta_{wl}$, the dual basis transform as
$$
\beta_{k} = \sum_{\mu =1}^2 A^{-1}_{k \mu }\beta'_{\mu},
$$
then for any $u \in V^*, v \in V$
\begin{align}
F(u,v) &= \sum_{k=1}^{2} T(\beta_k,u,w_k,v) \\ &= \sum_{k=1}^{2} T\Big(\sum_{\mu =1}^2 A^{-1}_{k \mu }\beta'_{\mu},u,\sum_{\alpha = 1}^{2} A_{\alpha k} w'_{\alpha},v\Big) \\
&= \sum_{\mu =1}^2 \sum_{\alpha = 1}^{2}  \, \Big(\sum_{k=1}^{2}  A^{-1}_{k \mu } A_{\alpha k}\Big)  T(\beta'_{\mu},u,w'_{\alpha},v) \\
&= \sum_{\mu =1}^2 \sum_{\alpha = 1}^{2}\delta_{\mu \alpha} T(\beta'_{\mu},u,w'_{\alpha},v) \\&=
\sum_{\alpha=1}^{2} T(\beta'_{\alpha},u,w'_{\alpha},v).
\end{align}
As @Ivo Terek says, this work for any (finite) dimension of $V$.

Comment: +1, very clear answer. OP should also note that this holds for $\dim V = n < +\infty$.

Comment: Sou 燈馬 想 and @IvoTerek, There is only one point which isn't clear to me. Could you help me? In the post we have
$$\delta_{\mu\alpha}=\sum_k A^{-1}_{k \mu} A_{\alpha k}.$$
However, in my calculation:
\begin{align*}\delta_{\mu\alpha }&=\beta'_\mu(w'_\alpha)
=\left(\sum_k A^{-1}_{\mu k} \beta_k\right)(w'_\alpha)
=\sum_k A^{-1}_{\mu k} \beta_k(w'_\alpha)
=\sum_k A^{-1}_{\mu k} \beta_k\left(\sum_m A_{m\alpha} w_m\right)\\
&=\sum_k \sum_m A^{-1}_{\mu k} A_{m\alpha} \beta_k\left(  w_m\right)=\sum_k \sum_m A^{-1}_{\mu k} A_{m\alpha} \delta_{km}=\sum_k A^{-1}_{\mu k} A_{k \alpha}.
\end{align*}.

Comment: Why $\sum_k A^{-1}_{k \mu} A_{\alpha k}= \sum_k A^{-1}_{\mu k} A_{k \alpha}$?

Comment: The sum there is just the sum of multiplications of real numbers. So its commutative. The left hand side is just entries of $AA^{-1}$. While the right is $A^{-1}A$.

Comment: So maybe in the calculations above i should put $\delta_{\alpha \mu}$
not the other, if we want to be strict. But $\delta_{\mu\alpha}=\delta_{\alpha\mu}$ so its not really matter.

Comment: @Sou燈馬想 It seems that putting $\delta_{\alpha \mu}$ does not solve the problem. In my calculation above, $\delta_{\alpha\mu}= \sum_k A^{-1}_{\alpha k} A_{k \mu}$. Why should this be equal to the sum $\sum_k A^{-1}_{k \mu} A_{\alpha k}$ which appears in your calculation?

Comment: It should be $w'_{\alpha} =\sum_l A^{-1}_{l \alpha}w_{l}$ and $\beta'_{\mu} = \sum_{j} A_{\mu j} \beta_j$

Comment: @Sou燈馬想 I understand it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**This solution can be used to prove the same result for an arbitrary finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over an arbitrary field $\mathbb{K}$, without any modification.**

We consider $\phi:X\to Y$, where $X:= V\otimes V\otimes V^*\otimes V^*$ and $Y:V\otimes V^*$, to be the linear map given by the contraction via the natural paring of the first factor and the third factor.  That is,
$$\phi(x\otimes y\otimes f\otimes g)=f(x)\,(y\otimes g)$$
for every $x,y\in V$ and $f,g\in V^*$.  The definition of $\phi$ is, of course, independent of the bases of $V$ and $V^*$ (i.e., $\phi$ is a canonical map).

Since $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space (whence so is $V^*$), the natural embeddings 
$$V\otimes V\otimes V^*\otimes V^* \hookrightarrow V^{**}\otimes V^{**}\otimes V^*\otimes V^*$$
and $$V^{**}\otimes V^{**}\otimes V^*\otimes V^*\hookrightarrow \left(V^*\otimes V^*\otimes V\otimes V\right)^*$$
become natural isomorphisms (the first one is induced by the canonical inclusion $V\hookrightarrow V^{**}$ and the second one is a consequence of the existence of a natural inclusion $U^*\otimes W^*\hookrightarrow \left(U\otimes W\right)^*$ for vector spaces $U$ and $W$).  That is, their composition
$$V\otimes V\otimes V^*\otimes V^* \hookrightarrow \left(V^*\otimes V^*\otimes V\otimes V\right)^*\,.$$
is a natural isomorphism of finite-dimensional vector spaces.  Thus, we can canonically (i.e., independent of bases) identify
$$X=V\otimes V\otimes V^*\otimes V^* \boldsymbol{=\!=}\left(V^*\otimes V^*\otimes V\otimes V\right)^*\,.$$
Similarly, there is a canonical identification
$$Y=V\otimes V^* \boldsymbol{=\!=} \left(V^*\otimes V\right)^*\,.$$
(The canonical identifications are denoted by long equal signs $\boldsymbol{=\!=}$.)

Note that the map $\phi$ takes each multilinear function $T\in \left(V^*\otimes V^*\otimes V\otimes V\right)^*\boldsymbol{=\!=}X$ to its associate $F\in \left(V^*\otimes V\right)^*\boldsymbol{=\!=}Y$.  Since $\phi$ is a canonical map, $F$ is independent of the choice of the basis of $V$.